# Why Spring Context is loaded twice?

Tags: java, spring

I have web project with Spring and Spring security.
My web.xml:

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0" >
        <display-name>BillBoard
        </display-name>
        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
        </listener>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:security-config.xml classpath:billboard-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>billboard</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>classpath:security-config.xml classpath:billboard-servlet.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>billboard</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

In server logs I see Spring context is loaded twice (spring bean initialization, database createtion...). At first time DispatcherServlet does it, and at the secont time ContextLoaderListener. How can I fix it?

In [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html) tutorial I see that if contextParam is presented then servlet init-params are not required. But if I remove init params I have error: "org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/billboard-servlet.xml]". Dispather servlet finds context-configuration in default location.

Answer (score 6):

You still need a context for your servlet:

> Upon initialization of a DispatcherServlet, Spring MVC looks for a file named [servlet-name]-servlet.xml in the WEB-INF directory of your web application and creates the beans defined there, overriding the definitions of any beans defined with the same name in the global scope.

You don't need to load it as `context-param` in the `ContextLoaderListener` though.

Just leave the `security-config.xml` as `context-param` (it has to go there, as security is global per application), and `billboard-servlet.xml` as `contextConfigLocation` of your servlet and it should work.

Comment: For Authentication I user DataBase, so I defined dataSource in billboard-servlet.xml and reference it like property in my AuthenticationProvider.

Comment: if your datasource is used outside your servlet it shouldn't be in `billboard-servlet.xml`. Put it in your root context - the servlet will inherit it anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and the reason was:

`<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup`

Answer (score 2):

These are two independent methods to do the same thing. Drop the `ContextLoaderListener`, for example.

Comment: If I drop contextLoaderListener then I have Exception "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?"

Comment: And if you drop `contextConfigLocation`?

Comment: I tried remove Context param or init-param from DispatcherServlet, but both options throws errors.

Comment: Then you need to post complete details on those errors. Stacktraces, for start.

Comment: I modified question, please look at it again.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik What if the same bean loaded twice? Will they create different instance and occupy memory?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have spring `delegatingFilterProxy`, if you drop `contextLoaderLister` you will get the below exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: 
no   ContextLoaderListener registered?
```

So load security-config.xml via contextLoaderLister and billboard-servlet.xml via dispatcher servlet.

Answer (score 1):

When you configure the spring MVC framework configuration in the XML, you may configure it as bellow:

```
<!-- for Spring context loader -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>billboard</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:security-config.xml classpath:billboard-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>
```

this configuration will cause the IoC container initialize twice.

You should change the default servlet name[billboard] to others to solve this problem.

Because your dispatcher servlet is using the default context namespace [name of servlet]-servlet.xml
(in the case billboard-servlet.xml) then Spring MVC will automatically load it.

For more details see: https://www.conqtech.com/blog/?p=85