# How to avoid "Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started" loading twice?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am using Spring MVC, Spring security and deploying in Apache Tomcat 1.7x. I notice that Web Application context is getting loaded twice. Please let me know what is wrong with my configuration.

I have referred below posts but could not identify the difference
[Why Spring Context is loaded twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409237/why-spring-context-is-loaded-twice), 
[Spring MVC web app: application context starts twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951257/spring-mvc-web-app-application-context-starts-twice)

> INFO  ContextLoader:273 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization
>   started

Below is my **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlet and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <!-- Spring Security Filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My **spring-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <beans:bean id="roleVoter"
        class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
        <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value=""></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:import resource="servlet-context.xml" />

    <beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager"
        class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="decisionVoters"
            ref="roleVoter" />
    </beans:bean>

    <http authentication-manager-ref="login-service"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
....
    </http>



    <beans:bean id="userLoginService" class="my.test.service.impl.UserLoginService">
        <beans:property name="userProfileService" ref="userProfileService" />
    </beans:bean>




    <!-- Login message -->
    <beans:bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basenames">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>mymessages</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring MVC web app: application context starts twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951257/spring-mvc-web-app-application-context-starts-twice)

Answer (score 0):

There are more than way to do this. The way that will work depends how `servlet-context.xml` are.

First, you can just remove `<beans:import resource="servlet-context.xml" />` from your `spring-security.xml`.

Other way is remove this:

```xml
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And this:

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And include an import to `spring-security.xml` in `servlet-context.xml`.

A good practice is separate your configuration in multiple *application contexts*, import all in an `applicationContext.xml` and have a specific *application context* for the servlet context, something like this:

`applicationContext.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.package" />

    <import resource="applicationContext-security.xml"/>
    <import resource="applicationContext-data.xml"/>

</beans>
```

`applicationContext-servlet.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" p:order="3" p:defaultErrorView="error" />

</beans>
```

And in your `web.xml`:

```xml
<!-- spring servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:META-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: thanks for your response. But removing either does not resolve bean dependencies and hence throws error.

Comment: @ad-inf if you remove the import from spring-security.xml, you can't resolve beans? How looks your servlet-context.xml? Improved the answer, see if now helps you.